# What is difference between configuration and and env variables of spark?

Tags: apache-spark, admin

There is some configuration I confuse like

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled = true  
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors = 3
spark.eventLog.dir=/home/rabindra/etl/logs
SPARK_WORKER_DIR=/home/knoldus/work/sparkdata
```

Where these variable of spark i will use spark-env.sh or spark-defaults.conf?
What are the configuration we can do in spark standalone  cluster ?

Answer (score 2):

The first three go in `spark-defaults.conf`. The last goes into `spark-env.sh` as shown in this [Knoldus example](https://blog.knoldus.com/2015/04/14/setup-a-apache-spark-cluster-in-your-single-standalone-machine/)--maybe the one you're using.

I suppose an analogy might be the difference between JVM arguments and environment variables. As shown in the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html), the configurations you want to apply to a `SparkConf`, like the application name, the URI of the master, or memory allocation, are on a *per-application* basis.

Meanwhile, environment variables, whether related to Spark or anything else, apply on a *per-machine* basis. Of course sometimes the machine-specific settings you would specify with an environment variable belong instead in your resource manager like YARN.

The list of configuration parameters is large. See the documentation linked above for more.